Planck's Law frequency vs wavelength
I was plotting planck's law today and attempted two different implementations.  I took both from this table on Wikipedia.  They are:

In terms of wavelength:

$$
B_{\lambda }(\lambda ,T)={\frac {2hc^{2}}{\lambda ^{5}}}{\frac {1}{\exp\left({\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}}\right) - 1}}
$$

In terms of frequency:

$$
B_{\nu }(\nu ,T)={\frac {2h\nu ^{3}}{c^{2}}}{\frac {1}{\exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{kT}\right)-1}}
$$
When I plotted these however, I got very different results:

This prompted me to actually look at the two equations, at which point I began to think they don't appear to be equal.  If I take:
$$
\lambda = \frac{c}{\nu}
$$
And substitute that into $B_{\lambda}(\lambda,T)$, then I get:
$$
\begin{align}
&= {\frac {2hc^{2}}{\left(\frac{c}{\nu}\right)^{5}}}{\frac {1}{\exp\left(hc/(\frac{c}{\nu} kT)\right)-1}}\\
&= {\frac {2h\nu ^{5}}{c^{3}}}{\frac {1}{\exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{kT}\right)-1}}
\end{align}
$$
Now evaluating this new function yields the correct result, yet this appears to just be a different function than the one I keep finding online.  It differs by an extra factor of $\nu^2/c$
What am I missing?  I'm assuming that there aren't just a bunch of typos online, and that I'm instead misunderstanding something more fundamental here.

Possible duplicate

Wikipedia: Correspondence between spectral variable forms

The Planck's law is a probability density, and you have to be careful how densities transform under change of variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239588/derivation-of-change-of-variables-of-a-probability-density-function
